# How to prevent 500 Error for multiple subdomain rewrite rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

In my .htacccess-file, I have two rewrite rules but can't get both working properly. Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^administration/ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) administration/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above code results in this:

- admin.example.com - 500 Internal Server Error
- example.com - Works fine

But if I uncomment the second line and run `RewriteRule ^administration/ - [L]`, the result is:

- admin.example.com - Works fine
- example.com - 500 Internal Server Error

I'm actually not sure about what the second line actually doing. I'm not so good at htaccess rewrite coding. I found that line from [another question here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521979/subdomain-redirection-with-htaccess-and-a-500-internal-server-error).

And about the 500 error, I thought it caused by an infinite loop. But can't really see how it could appear by my code. So would really like to get that explained.

So, I would really like to get answers to this:

1. What does line 2 means, especially the "-" character there?
2. And what causes the 500 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500 is probably due to infinite looping, try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!administration/).*)$ administration/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: That solved it. Big thanks. If you want to explain what caused the loop and what you did, it would really be appreciated. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Problem was in this rule: `RewriteRule (.*) administration/$1 [L]` since it was unconditionally routing every request to `/administration` and when mod_rewrite kept running again & again since this rule didn't stop rewriting. With negative lookahead regex in my answer it stops after first time rewrite.

Comment: Okay now this lead to a new problem, which perhaps maybe should be a question of it's own. But I have a copy of the same htaccess file in the administration (what I remembered is named "test" for real). This is causing a new infinite loop. Which I this time understand why, but can't figure out how to avoid. I want to keep have the exact same code in both files. Is it possible to have a condition that checks which directory you are in?

Comment: htaccess is per directory directive so things have to change as per the directory it belongs to. Yes you're right it definitely sounds like a new question. I have some ideas on how to make same rule work on both sub-directories (independent of this answer) that I would like to share with you as a separate answer to your new question.

Comment: Yes, I have now created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776310/how-avoid-infinite-loop-when-htaccess-rewrites-to-a-copy-of-same-htaccess-file