# How avoid infinite loop when htaccess rewrites to a copy of same htaccess-file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, infinite-loop

I have this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =test.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!test/).*)$ test/$1 [L,NC]
```

And a completely identical copy of the same file in the "test" directory. So, of course, this leads to an infinite loop when the first file pass you to the second file running the rules again.

I have tried add the rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test [L,NC]` in hope that REQUEST_URI stood for the real path and not the new "alias". However, it didn't worked.

Is there any way to maybe check which directory we are in to use in a condition? Or any other solution to this problem? With the basis to keep the both file's codes identical.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Redirect everything going to `test.example.com` to `test.example.com/test`?

Comment: Everything going to `test.example.com` should be redirected to root folder `/test` except if you already are in- or have been redirected to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already in `test` directory there is no point to rewrite again to `test` directory using a **relative path**. It will be better to determine the `RewriteBase` dynamically and use absolute paths for rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On

# generate BASE dir in env variable %{ENV:BASE}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =test.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}test/$1 [L,NC]
```

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` is used to prevent rewriting **after first rewriting** of the rule since `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` becomes `200` after that.

Comment: Wow, I'm starting to think maybe it's a bit too complex and extra code for it's purpose. Had hoped for a small one-liner. Hmm, I have to think about this.

Comment: Yes a bit of complexity to make .htaccess agnostic to the sub-directory it is placed in.

Comment: Otherwise if you always know the sub-directory name then just use `RewriteBase /test/` and avoid dynamic rule.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, weird, but I now got it to work - simply like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =test.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!test/).*)$ test/$1 [L,NC]
```

**Edit:** Seems like it only works for the startpage. On other pages, the beginning trailing slash of the path is being removed.